# Apache NiFi - Move table content from Oracle to Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, oracle, apache-nifi

[image][image: I am very new to Apache Nifi. I am trying to Migrate data from Oracle to Mongo DB as per the screenshot in Apache NiFi. I am failing with the reported error. Pls help]

I am very new to Apache Nifi. I am trying to Migrate data from Oracle to Mongo DB as per the screenshot in Apache NiFi. I am failing with the reported error. Pls help.

1. Till PutFile i think its working fine, as i can see the below Json format file in my local directory.

Comment: It's working up to split.You have connection problem with MongoDB.Can you share connection string with MongoDB?

Comment: @Kumar, Pls refer the screen shot above for the connection details. i have masked the contents.

Comment: try with  `mongodb://host:port`

Comment: @Kumar, now it fails : "insert requires authentication". How do i provide the mongo DB credentials in the process properties ? i see no options to enter it?

Comment: Why did you set client auth required but no SSL context service? Is this Production?

Comment: If not a production server set client auth to none  and If user and password required to login database change  URI  to `mongodb://username:password@hostname:portnumber`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple setup direct from Oracle Database to MongoDb without SSL or username and password (not recommended for Production)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Just keep tinkering on PutMongoRecord Processor until you resolve all outstanding issues and exclamation mark is cleared

Answer (score 0):

I am first using an ExecuteSQL processor which is resulting the dataset in Avro, I need the final data in JSON. In DBconnection pooling Service, you need to create a controller with the credentials of your Orcale database. Post that I am using Split Avro and then Transform XML to convert it into JSON. In Transform XML, you need to use XSLT file. After that, I use PutMongo Processor for ingestion in Json which gets automatically converted in BSON